# Django redirect appends the url to the previous one

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect from an url `/alerta/3304557/` to one `/alerta/rio` using the `redirect('/alerta/rio/')` call. `/alerta/rio/` works just fine when typed in manually.

But redirect is issuing a redirect to `http://localhost:8000/alerta/3304557/alerta/rio` which obviously causes a 404 error since that URL does not exist.

Relevant lines of code:

`url(r'^alerta/rio/$', AlertaPageView.as_view(), name='mrj'),`

`url(r'^alerta/(?P<geocodigo>\d{7})/$', AlertaPageViewMunicipio.as_view(), name='alerta_cidade'),`

```
class AlertaPageViewMunicipio(TemplateView):
template_name = 'alerta_municipio.html'

# def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
#     municipio_gc = kwargs['geocodigo']
#     if int(municipio_gc) == 3304557: # Rio de Janeiro
#         return redirect(AlertaPageView, permanent=True, *args, **kwargs)
#     return super(AlertaPageViewMunicipio, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AlertaPageViewMunicipio, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    municipio_gc = context['geocodigo']
    if int(municipio_gc) == 3304557: # Rio de Janeiro
        args = tuple([])
        return redirect('/alerta/rio/', permanent=False, *args, **kwargs)
    city_info = get_city_info(municipio_gc)
    alert, SE, case_series, last_year, observed_cases, min_max_est, dia = dbdata.get_city_alert(municipio_gc)
    casos_ap = {municipio_gc: int(case_series[-1])}
    bairros = {municipio_gc: city_info['nome']}
    total_series = case_series[-12:]
    total_observed_series = observed_cases[-12:]
    context.update({
        'nome': city_info['nome'],
        'casos_por_ap': json.dumps(casos_ap),
        'alerta': {municipio_gc: alert},
        'novos_casos': case_series[-1],
        'bairros': bairros,
        'min_est': min_max_est[0],
        'max_est': min_max_est[1],
        'series_casos': {municipio_gc: case_series[-12:]},
        'SE': SE,
        'data1': (dia - datetime.timedelta(2)).strftime("%d de %B de %Y"),
        'data2': (dia + datetime.timedelta(4)).strftime("%d de %B de %Y"),
        'last_year': last_year,
        'look_back': len(total_series),
        'total_series': ', '.join(map(str, total_series)),
        'total_observed': total_observed_series[-1],
        'total_observed_series': ', '.join(map(str, total_observed_series)),
        'geocodigo': municipio_gc,
    })
    return context
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the relevant urls?

Comment: Is this your actual code? You might have omitted the leading slash.

Comment: Do you definitely have `redirect('/alerta/rio/')`? If you did `redirect('alerta/rio')` without the leading/trailing slashes, then I would expect it to redirect to `/alerta/3304557/alerta/rio`

Comment: These are not the relevant lines of code. The relevant line would be the bit from the view where you actually return the redirect.

Comment: Updated  with the call to redirect

Comment: `get_context_data` should return a dictionary containing the context. It should never return an HTTP response. I would expect that method to raise an error, not to redirect to the wrong location. Please show the entire `AlertaPageViewMunicipio` view.

Comment: @Alasdair there you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to perform redirect in [**dispatch method**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch):

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    municipio_gc = kwargs.get('geocodigo', 0)
    if int(municipio_gc) == 3304557: # Rio de Janeiro
        args = tuple([])
        return redirect('/alerta/rio/')

    return super(AlertaPageViewMunicipio, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Note:** Your `'/alerta/rio/'` view doesn't accept any parameters so **avoid passing *args and  **kwargs** while performing redirect.

**Update:**

As **@Alasdair** pointed it's better to get `geocodigo` from ****kwargs** instead of calling  `get_context_data` to access value of `context['geocodigo']`.

Comment: @fccoelho which problem you had while moving logic to dispatch ?

Comment: Just tried again and got the same error: 404. It is still appending the url on the original: Request URL: http://localhost:8000/alerta/3304557/alerta/rio

Comment: Try to call `redirect('mrj', *args, **kwargs)` instead and open page in another browser

Comment: Now I get a NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'mrj' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'geocodigo': '3304557'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['alerta/rio/$']

Comment: ok, got idea of problem, try to simply  execute `redirect('/alerta/rio/')` or `redirect('mrj')` those redirects should work well

Comment: The issue was indeed with the arguments!! I removed *args and **kwargs from the redirect call. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for your suggestion) didn't catch that moment from beginning !

Answer (score 0):

You should be cautious of returning a redirect in get_context_data(), which expects to return a dict().  Try moving that logic to the get() function.

Comment: I have tried moving it to the dispatch method,  but had another error.

Comment: def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         municipio_gc = kwargs['geocodigo']
         if int(municipio_gc) == 3304557: # Rio de Janeiro
            return redirect(AlertaPageView, permanent=True, *args, **kwargs)
        return super(AlertaPageViewMunicipio, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: Just tried to add the redirect to the get method, and got the exact same problem.